# Tensorflow TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - tf.contrib.rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror, attributeerror, recurrent-neural-network

Had an issue with Attribute errors calling:

```
tf.nn.rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

Received an **Attribute error:**

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.nn' has no attribute 'rnn'
```

**Changed this to:**

```
tf.contrib.rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

However, now I receive the following **error**:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**against the following line:**

```
states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

the code looks as follows:

```
# Forward passes
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

**Full Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/glennhealy/PycharmProjects/lstm2/lstm2.py", line 49, in <module>
    states_series, current_state = tf.contrib.rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any Ideas??

**tf.nn.rnn** doesn't work, but neither does **tf.contrib.rnn**

Cheers in advance

**Updated with more information based on responses**

Looking at this, I have tried all the options in the tensorflgw_RNN information and I'm getting this error for a lot of them:

```
TypeError: static_bidirectional_rnn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial_state'
```

so, now I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

According to the document 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.rnn

TensorFlow provides a number of methods for constructing Recurrent Neural Networks.

```
tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn
tf.contrib.rnn.static_state_saving_rnn
tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn
tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
```

Try this

```
tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

or

```
tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

Comment: Nada, neither work. I end up with the same tenforflow Tensor shape error I had before

Comment: raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank at least %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape () must have rank at least 2